# AWS Lambda Post, Delete, Put request in Node js

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am really new is AWS devops. I have created one Dynamo db database. Then created `API GATEWAY` and connected with my LAMBDA function. I manually added the data in Dynamodb. I made API gateway cors origin and make it public API. I test my api endpoint by using `POSTMAN`.In Lambda function i used `scan` method. Now I have three more api end points which are `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` method. But I don't how to add those method in Lambda function.

**This is my Lambda function**

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient({region: 'us-east-1'});

exports.handler = function(event, context, callback){

    let scanningParameters = {
        TableName: 'studentTable'
    };

    
    docClient.scan(scanningParameters, function(err,data){
        if(err){
            callback(err, null);
        }else{
 
            callback(null,data.Items);
        }
    });
    
   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you create for **every** HTTP-Method a lambda, for example a Lambda for `getStudent`, a Lambda for `deleteStudent` etc.

Otherwise you could check for the HTTP-Method in the **API-Gateway event**, which your Lambda gets and process the request accordingly.

Comment: Can you please show me one example, Lambda HTTP method.

Answer (score 0):

In the var event, you have the type of request (GET,PUT,DELETE,...), you can do a switch case or if..else concatenation. You can also create diferent functions for every HTTP-method to lambda, so your GET method from your resource /student will invoke the getStudent lambda function, your PUT method from your resource /student will invoke the addStudent lambda function, etc

For example, I have this:

[image]

I have 2 methods for /cash resource.

[image]

This GET method invokes a getCash lambda function

[image]

This POST method invokes a addCash lambda function

As I mentioned, if you print the var event, you will get:

```
{'resource': '/categories', 'path': '/categories', 'httpMethod': 'GET', 'headers': {'accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',.......}
```

You can use the httpMethod to do a switch case or if else concatenation.

I do it in python, will be somehting like this:

```
if event['httpMethod']=="GET":
   do something
else if event['httpMethod']=="PUT":
   do something
```

Fell free to ask,

Hope i help you.

Comment: Really sorry for late reply. Do you know how to do it node-js.